Convert a list of from columns to rows grouped by customer name via SQL
I have scoured Stack overflow for solution and I see solutions that dance around my question but miss the mark...so here goes -
I have a file that looks like the following -



CustNam
Balance
Curr




AAA
100
USD


AAA
2000
JPY


AAA
500
EUR


AAA
650
GBP


BBB
445
SGD


BBB
987
USD


BBB
980
ZAR


CCC
300
CHF



I'm seeking an SQL solution that will convert the columns to rows based on customer grouping. So my out put should look like this :



CustNam
Balance1
Balance2
Balance3
Balances4
Balance5




AAA
100
2000
500
650



BBB
445
987
980




CCC
300







I'm indifferent to the other fields (i.e. Curr) and just need to create a row of data per customer rather than a list/column of data.
What is the most efficient SQL code that can aid me?
